# Одна функция навсегда

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

У меня есть кусок кода

```
$('[maxlength][minlength]').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).after('<div></div>');obj=$(this).parent().find('div')
    }
).bind('keyup focus',
    function(){
        if ($(this).attr('minlength')>this.value.length){
            obj.text(($(this).attr('minlength')-this.value.length)+' символов нужно');
        }else{
            obj.text(($(this).attr('maxlength')-this.value.length)+' символов осталось');
            if (this.value.length>$(this).attr('maxlength')){
                this.value=this.value.substring(0,this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
            }
        }
    }
).blur(
    function(){
        obj.remove();
    }
);
```

Суть его в том, что при фокусировке на объектах в которых есть атрибуты maxlength и minlength, после них создается ДИВ в котором отображается сколько символов нужно и осталось.

Суть проблемы такова, этот скрипт работает только на созданных заранее объектах (засунут в `$(document).ready()`), а мне необходимо, чтобы он работал всегда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод [live()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9). Т.е. код будет выглядеть так:

```
$('[maxlength][minlength]').live('focus',
    function(){
        $(this).after('<div></div>');obj=$(this).parent().find('div')
    }
).live('keyup focus',
    function(){
        if ($(this).attr('minlength')>this.value.length){
            obj.text(($(this).attr('minlength')-this.value.length)+' символов нужно');
        }else{
            obj.text(($(this).attr('maxlength')-this.value.length)+' символов осталось');
            if (this.value.length>$(this).attr('maxlength')){
                this.value=this.value.substring(0,this.getAttribute('maxlength'));
            }
        }
    }
).live('blur',
    function(){
        obj.remove();
    }
);
```